# how to make a program wait until a button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to make a program wait until a button is clicked by the user.

I want to stop my sequence of codes (statements) until a button is clicked by the user.

how can I go this ?

Comment: Why don't you just not start them until they click? -- otherwise look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092431/c-how-do-i-pause-my-program-and-wait-for-keyboard-input-from-within-a-winform

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? .NET based languages are event driven so, as long as you put the code in the correct place (e.g. a button click event handler), nothing will execute unless something happens (like that button click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever it is that you want to happen after the button is clicked, just put that code in the handler for the button-click event. To get to that handler, double click on the button in the designer.